# Paypal SDK / Ruby on Rails / SetExpressCheckout

Tags: ruby, paypal, sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments

Finalizing an integration of paypal on some website;
I' like to pre-fill all fields besides the ones about the credit card.

With [this example here](https://paypal-sdk-samples.herokuapp.com/merchant/set_express_checkout) 
it is almost completely filled.

[image]

The only fields that remains are the ***email*** and the ***phone*** of the user; and as I require it on the shop's form before redirecting to paypal; I'd like it not to be asked again on the paypal form

Where does those two infos (email and phone) should be send to ? in which part of the structure ?
Thanks for any experiences about it

Comment: You can prevent asking of phone number on PayPal, check article http://docs.shopify.com/support/settings/checkout-and-payment/how-do-i-make-sure-orders-from-paypal-express-checkout-capture-a-phone-number

Comment: I'll try first to pass it in the params and have it filled. It does not solve the point about the email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check 'Automatically Filling Out Shipping and Contact Information' section at  [Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/)

Comment: Yep I ended up on this page. It is told here "Automatically Filling Out Shipping and Contact Information" > Request Parameters > PAYMENTREQUEST_0_EMAIL and PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM (I guess). thing is; you see that through the ruby SDK it does not really works with url parameters as used in the paypal examples; and I do not manage to do the "conversion"

Comment: In ruby SDK SOAP format of parameters is used (check https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_SOAP/) It seems parameters PAYMENTREQUEST_0_EMAIL and PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM are map to BuyerEmail and ShipToAddress#Phone fields.